# I have no idea where the error is anymore

Tags: javascript, return

I have no idea where the error is anymore. It was first saying that I had an unexpected identifier, then I had an unmatched }, now I have an illegal return statement. I just need some help. Thanks.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";

    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        } else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        } else {
            return "scissors wins";
        } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "paper wins";
            } else {
                return "scissors wins";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your missing a closing curly brace.

Comment: Does it work to set computerChoice as a number first and then as a string later? Just curious. I would probably have that be 2 variables, one for each type.

Comment: Line 31 has an "else if" which follows an "else".  That "Else If" will never be reached.  
In JavaScript it is OK for a variable to be a number and then later be a string.

Comment: @Caleb, your logic could be much simpler. Since you don't declare which player wins (just which weapon) or validate input, you can use the following logic: if tie (tie); else if either is rock and either is paper (paper win); else if either is rock and either is scissors (rock win); else (scissor win)

Comment: Yeah, Forklift. I know exactly what you're saying. It _could_ be much simplier. But, providing that this is a CodeAcademy lesson, they want exact syntax, and as a result, it is forced to be this way. :P

Comment: @Caleb, understood. I'm not actually familiar with that program, but it sounds like you got what you needed. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        } else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "paper wins";
            } else {
                return "scissors wins";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Properly indented code can help find missing curly braces.  By the time that something is indented 4 times, it's time to see if it can be refactored.

For example:

The first if has a return. There is no reason to have an "else if" after that.  That will get rid of one indent.  Same can be said of ("choice2 === "rock").  Trust that when a return is written that it will actually return.

Comment: As this looks like a codewars.com problem or another problem, I think it is best if you refactor it a little bit instead of receiving refactored code.  :)  Good luck, you'll get it.

Comment: geeves, thank you for the advice and the help! It really helped me and made me see my error. Thank you. Up voted for the feedback and the explanation.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer Caleb, I was in your shoes a while ago. Refactoring can be fun and is rewarding 99% of the time.